# DHCP Server not Authorized

Tags: dns, authorization, windows-server-2008, dhcp

I have two Active Directory servers performing both authentication and DNS.
One server is 2003 and the other is 2008.  It is my understanding that there is no primary Domain server in this scenario and that everything will replicate from 2003 to 2008 without issue.

I have a 3rd virtual 2008 server which has been preforming DHCP for over 2 years without a problem.
It is now appearing that I cannot properly authorize DHCP (Red downward arrow).
When I attempt authorization, I do not get an error.  It simply does not function and appears to not be authorized. I also tried netsh for authorization.

I have an error in the logs of the DHCP stating:
"The DHCP Service failed to see a directory server for Authorization"

One change that was made recently was that I tried to revive the old physical DHCP server for performing another service.  I changed the IP and the Computer name before I networked it. I have since turned it off, but I believe that this is when the problem began.

What is the problem?
Additionally, are one of the AD servers more primary in the authorization of DHCP, or are they of equal authority?
Thanks

Note:  I have removed all outdated entries regarding DHCP from DNS.
Also, forest functionality level is set to Windows 2000, though we have nothing on our network older than XP.

Answer (score 0):

Your first domain controller in your network is the "primary" domain controller. The primary domain controller keeps **5 FSMO roles** of the entire Active Directory forest.

In your case, I think there might be some problems with DNS. Most of these types of problems were caused by DNS. You can try to use **DCDiag utility** to test the connection and DNS configuration from both domain controllers.

After fixing your DNS, you might want to restart the **Net Logon** service on both Domain Controller to refresh the SRV Record.

In the worst case that it happens to me, I had to dis-join the DHCP server (standalone server) from the domain, and join it back it, re-authorize it with AD.